# .htaccess -Redirect both domain and subdomain to https

Tags: html, .htaccess, http-redirect

I want to redirect all my

http://example.org to https://example.org,

i also want to redirect subdomains

http://subdomain.example.org to https://subdomain.example.org.

Please how will i do this?